# getATR() does not reset the smart card in javax.smartcardio

Tags: java, smartcard, apdu

I'm programming a small application for a smart card with Java using `javax.smartcardio` package, and I have a some problem with the ATR (Answer to reset). The `card.getATR()` method does not reset the card. It returns the ATR bytes, but it does not return the card to MF state.

That is my example:

```
TerminalFactory factory = TerminalFactory.getDefault();
List<CardTerminal> terminals = factory.terminals().list();

// get the first terminal
CardTerminal terminal = terminals.get(0);
// establish a connection with the card
Card card = terminal.connect("T=0");

ATR atr = card.getATR(); //atr.getBytes() <- correct

CardChannel channel = card.getBasicChannel();

ResponseAPDU r;
// STEP 1. select file in MF
r = channel.transmit(new CommandAPDU(new byte[]{0,(byte)0xA4,(byte)0x02,(byte)0x0C,(byte)0x02,0,(byte)0x02,0}));
// r.getBytes() == 90 00 <- correct

// STEP 2. select DF
r = channel.transmit(new CommandAPDU(new byte[]{0,(byte)0xA4,(byte)0x04,(byte)0x0C,(byte)0x02,(byte)0x05,0}));
// r.getBytes() == 90 00 <- correct

atr = card.getATR(); // answer to reset

// STEP 3. select file in MF, as in STEP 1
r = channel.transmit(new CommandAPDU(new byte[]{0,(byte)0xA4,(byte)0x02,(byte)0x0C,(byte)0x02,0,(byte)0x02,0}));
// r.getBytes() == 6A 82 <- fail, not found

card.disconnect(false);
```

Where is my mistake? Or how i can to reset the card?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Ro1 :)

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Next time I'll know ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Card.getATR()` does not specify that it resets the card. It simply returns the ATR that has been requested from the card. You should probably use [`disconnect(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/security/smartcardio/spec/javax/smartcardio/Card.html#disconnect%28boolean%29) instead, and then reconnect to the card.